# Sharp-nailed fingers vs Sharp-nail fingers?

Tags: sentence-construction

> 1) She has sharp-nailed fingers.
>
> 2) She has sharp-nail fingers.

Which is correct? and Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**She has sharp-nailed fingers** is correct. This is because, by using the word *sharp* before *nails* in that format, you are making the entire word, *sharp-nailed*, an adjective for the noun *fingers*.
If you use *sharp-nail*, the word *sharp* becomes the adjective only for the noun *nail* (the hyphen has no use then). So the usage of another noun consecutively after *nail*, becomes incorrect.

Comment: I agree that the former is an adjective (`sharp-nailed`), while the latter is an adjective-noun pair (`sharp-nail`), but it has nothing to do with the word sharp. `Nailed` can be an adjective (or verb), `nail` can't be. `She has nailed fingers` is still correct without the word "sharp" (though a fairly uninteresting sentence). `She has nail fingers` is only correct if you mean her fingers are like nails (the same way you could say somebody has fat `banana fingers` or spindly `spider fingers`).